# Jenkins: "Failed to launch Maven" Error

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3

I get the following error in Jenkins. I'm using Maven 3.0.4. Running on a Linux slave. Anyone have any solutions?

Error: Could not find or load main class org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main

ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1

Comment: Does maven work from command line? Do you have all necessary env variables set? Check out maven installation docs.

Comment: not enough information here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was not even related to the error message I was seeing. But nonetheless, I had a step where I install custom tools using the custom tools plugin. I never used the tools, but just installed them. And this gave me the above error.

Comment: Please provide more information on your solution. It can be helpfull for other people here